# ESP32 printing weird chars infinitely, maybe due to EMI (Electromagnetic Interference)

Tags: arduino, electron, serial-port, esp32, arduino-esp32

I am working on ESP32 WebSocket communication. And after lot of hard work I'm facing serious problem that, In Serial Monitor Esp32 is printing weird chars infinitely. so to run esp32 perfectly every time I have to restart my esp32 board.

Esp32 board controlling devices(bulb, tube light, sockets etc.) perfectly but this problem occurring only with fan whenever I try to control using remotely or manually. But  it running very smoothly on breadboard or when I'm not powering relay module with AC voltage.
[Image of Error in Serial Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVeJZ.png)

I tried different different connections but problem is same.
when this problem is occurring
Case1. when fan connected with relay and trying to ON/OFF remotely or manually.
Case2. fan is disconnected from relay but connected with manual switch and trying to
ON/OFF.

I figured out or maybe I'm wrong that whenever I'm trying to control fan, it produce high EMI(Electromagnetic Interference) and that EMI cause an error(printing random chars infinitely in serial monitor) to ESP32.

[Here is the main Circuit Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl2HL.jpg)

Here is the code:-

```
#include <ArduinoWebsockets.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#define ESP_NAME "Room 1"
//-----------------Appliances/Relay pins declaration or OUTPUT PINS------------------
#define Tubelight 22
#define Bulb 23
#define Fan 18
#define Socket1 19

//---------------Switches pin declaration or INPUT PINS-------------------
#define switch1 32
#define switch2 33
#define switch3 25
#define switch4 26

//--------------------Network Credentials------------------------------
const char* ssid = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"; //Enter SSID
const char* password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"; //Enter Password
const char* websockets_connection_string = "wss://xxxxxxxx.glitch.me"; //server address

//------------------Eliminate Switch buttons debounce effect--------------------
unsigned long lastDebounceTime = 0;
int debounceDelay = 600;

//------------------------Switches Previous state---------------------
bool switch1_prev_state = HIGH; //here HIGH work as LOW in INPUT_PULLUP pinMode
bool switch2_prev_state = HIGH;
bool switch3_prev_state = HIGH;
bool switch4_prev_state = HIGH;

bool wb_config_state = false;

//------------------------Websocket Variables------------------------------
using namespace websockets;
WebsocketsClient clientt;
StaticJsonDocument<200> doc; //for parsing data sent from server

// This certificate was updated 15.04.2021, issues on Mar 15th 2021, expired on June 13th 2021
const char echo_org_ssl_ca_cert[] PROGMEM = \
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
"MIIEZTCCA02gAwIBAgIQQAF1BIMUpMghjISpDBbN3zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA/\n" \
"MSQwIgYDVQQKExtEaWdpdGFsIFNpZ25hdHVyZSBUcnVzdCBDby4xFzAVBgNVBAMT\n" \
"DkRTVCBSb290IENBIFgzMB4XDTIwMTAwNzE5MjE0MFoXDTIxMDkyOTE5MjE0MFow\n" \
"MjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFjAUBgNVBAoTDUxldCdzIEVuY3J5cHQxCzAJBgNVBAMT\n" \
"AlIzMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuwIVKMz2oJTTDxLs\n" \
"jVWSw/iC8ZmmekKIp10mqrUrucVMsa+Oa/l1yKPXD0eUFFU1V4yeqKI5GfWCPEKp\n" \
"Tm71O8Mu243AsFzzWTjn7c9p8FoLG77AlCQlh/o3cbMT5xys4Zvv2+Q7RVJFlqnB\n" \
"U840yFLuta7tj95gcOKlVKu2bQ6XpUA0ayvTvGbrZjR8+muLj1cpmfgwF126cm/7\n" \
"gcWt0oZYPRfH5wm78Sv3htzB2nFd1EbjzK0lwYi8YGd1ZrPxGPeiXOZT/zqItkel\n" \
"/xMY6pgJdz+dU/nPAeX1pnAXFK9jpP+Zs5Od3FOnBv5IhR2haa4ldbsTzFID9e1R\n" \
"oYvbFQIDAQABo4IBaDCCAWQwEgYDVR0TAQH/BAgwBgEB/wIBADAOBgNVHQ8BAf8E\n" \
"BAMCAYYwSwYIKwYBBQUHAQEEPzA9MDsGCCsGAQUFBzAChi9odHRwOi8vYXBwcy5p\n" \
"ZGVudHJ1c3QuY29tL3Jvb3RzL2RzdHJvb3RjYXgzLnA3YzAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBTE\n" \
"p7Gkeyxx+tvhS5B1/8QVYIWJEDBUBgNVHSAETTBLMAgGBmeBDAECATA/BgsrBgEE\n" \
"AYLfEwEBATAwMC4GCCsGAQUFBwIBFiJodHRwOi8vY3BzLnJvb3QteDEubGV0c2Vu\n" \
"Y3J5cHQub3JnMDwGA1UdHwQ1MDMwMaAvoC2GK2h0dHA6Ly9jcmwuaWRlbnRydXN0\n" \
"LmNvbS9EU1RST09UQ0FYM0NSTC5jcmwwHQYDVR0OBBYEFBQusxe3WFbLrlAJQOYf\n" \
"r52LFMLGMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjANBgkqhkiG9w0B\n" \
"AQsFAAOCAQEA2UzgyfWEiDcx27sT4rP8i2tiEmxYt0l+PAK3qB8oYevO4C5z70kH\n" \
"ejWEHx2taPDY/laBL21/WKZuNTYQHHPD5b1tXgHXbnL7KqC401dk5VvCadTQsvd8\n" \
"S8MXjohyc9z9/G2948kLjmE6Flh9dDYrVYA9x2O+hEPGOaEOa1eePynBgPayvUfL\n" \
"qjBstzLhWVQLGAkXXmNs+5ZnPBxzDJOLxhF2JIbeQAcH5H0tZrUlo5ZYyOqA7s9p\n" \
"O5b85o3AM/OJ+CktFBQtfvBhcJVd9wvlwPsk+uyOy2HI7mNxKKgsBTt375teA2Tw\n" \
"UdHkhVNcsAKX1H7GNNLOEADksd86wuoXvg==\n" \
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";

void onMessageCallback(WebsocketsMessage message)//get messages From server
{
    Serial.print("Got Message: ");
    Serial.println(message.data());

    // Deserialize the JSON document
    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, message.data());
  
    // Test if parsing succeeds.
    if (error){
      Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
      Serial.println(error.f_str());
      return;
    }

    //store status of appliance
    bool sts = doc["status"]=="ON"?LOW:HIGH; //here relay work in reverse
    if(doc["room_name"] == ESP_NAME)
    {
      if(doc["appliance"] == "Tubelight")
      {
        digitalWrite(Tubelight, sts);
      }
      else if(doc["appliance"] == "Bulb")
      {
        digitalWrite(Bulb, sts);
      }
      else if(doc["appliance"] == "Fan")
      {
        digitalWrite(Fan, sts);
      }
      else if(doc["appliance"] == "Socket1")
      {
        digitalWrite(Socket1, sts);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("False Room Name");
    }
}

void onEventsCallback(WebsocketsEvent event, String data) {
    if(event == WebsocketsEvent::ConnectionOpened) {
        Serial.println("Connnection Opened");
    } else if(event == WebsocketsEvent::ConnectionClosed) {
        Serial.println("Connnection Closed");
        wb_config_state = false;
//        clientt.connect(websockets_connection_string);
    } else if(event == WebsocketsEvent::GotPing) {
        Serial.println("Got a Ping!");
    } else if(event == WebsocketsEvent::GotPong) {
        Serial.println("Got a Pong!");
    }
}
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password); //Connecting to wifi
    while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(200);
    }
    Serial.println("\nSuccessfully Connected with WiFi.");
     
    //-------------------Pinmode Setup----------------------
    //for relay or output
    pinMode(Tubelight, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Bulb, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Fan, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Socket1, OUTPUT);

    //pinMode for Switches
    pinMode(switch1, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(switch2, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(switch3, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(switch4, INPUT_PULLUP);

    //-----------Prevent relay from jump start----------------
    digitalWrite(Tubelight, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Bulb, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Fan, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Socket1, HIGH);
}

void loop() 
{
  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    if(wb_config_state==false){
      wb_config();
      wb_config_state = true;
    }else{clientt.poll();}
  }
  else{
    WiFi.reconnect();
  }
    mannual(); 
}
void wb_config()
{
  //--------------------Websocket communication establishment-------------------
    clientt.onMessage(onMessageCallback);// run callback when messages are received
    clientt.onEvent(onEventsCallback);// run callback when events are occuring
    clientt.setCACert(echo_org_ssl_ca_cert);// Before connecting, set the ssl fingerprint of the server
    clientt.addHeader("User-Agent", "Satya");//Add header
    clientt.connect(websockets_connection_string);// Connect to server
    clientt.ping();// Send a ping
}
void mannual()
{
  //--------------------------------Switch 1----------------------------------
  if((digitalRead(switch1)==HIGH)&& switch1_prev_state==LOW && debounce())
  {
//    Serial.println("Switch 1 / Tubelight --> OFF");
    build_send_data("Tubelight", "OFF");
    digitalWrite(Tubelight, HIGH);
    switch1_prev_state = HIGH;
    lastDebounceTime = millis();
  }
  if(digitalRead(switch1)==LOW && switch1_prev_state==HIGH && debounce())
  {
//    Serial.println("Switch 1 / Tubelight --> ON");
    build_send_data("Tubelight", "ON");
    digitalWrite(Tubelight, LOW);
    switch1_prev_state = LOW;
    lastDebounceTime = millis();
  }
  
  //--------------------------------Switch 2----------------------------------
  if((digitalRead(switch2)==HIGH)&& switch2_prev_state==LOW && debounce())
  {
//    Serial.println("Switch 2 / Bulb --> OFF");
    build_send_data("Bulb", "OFF");
    digitalWrite(Bulb, HIGH);
    switch2_prev_state = HIGH;
    lastDebounceTime = millis();
  }
  if(digitalRead(switch2)==LOW && switch2_prev_state==HIGH && debounce())
  {
//    Serial.println("Switch 2 / Bulb --> ON");
    build_send_data("Bulb", "ON");
    digitalWrite(Bulb, LOW);
    switch2_prev_state = LOW;
    lastDebounceTime = millis();
  }

  //--------------------------------Switch 3----------------------------------
  if((digitalRead(switch3)==HIGH)&& switch3_prev_state==LOW && debounce())
  {
//    Serial.println("Switch 3 / Fan --> OFF");
    build_send_data("Fan", "OFF");
    digitalWrite(Fan, HIGH);
    switch3_prev_state = HIGH;
    lastDebounceTime = millis();
  }
  if(digitalRead(switch3)==LOW && switch3_prev_state==HIGH && debounce())
  {
//    Serial.println("Switch 3 / Fan --> ON");
    build_send_data("Fan", "ON");
    digitalWrite(Fan, LOW);
    switch3_prev_state = LOW;
    lastDebounceTime = millis();
  }

  //--------------------------------Switch 4----------------------------------
  if((digitalRead(switch4)==HIGH)&& switch4_prev_state==LOW && debounce())
  {
//    Serial.println("Switch 4 / Socket1 --> OFF");
    build_send_data("Socket1", "OFF");
    digitalWrite(Socket1, HIGH);
    switch4_prev_state = HIGH;
    lastDebounceTime = millis();
  }
  if(digitalRead(switch4)==LOW && switch4_prev_state==HIGH && debounce())
  {
//    Serial.println("Switch 4 / Socket1 --> ON");
    build_send_data("Socket1", "ON");
    digitalWrite(Socket1, LOW);
    switch4_prev_state = LOW;
    lastDebounceTime = millis();
  }
}
void build_send_data(String appliance, String sts)
{
  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    doc["from"] = "ESP32";
    doc["client_name"] = ESP_NAME;
    doc["room_name"] = "Room 1";
    doc["appliance"] = appliance;
    doc["status"] = sts; 
  
    String send_data;
    serializeJson(doc, send_data);
  
    Serial.print("Send Message : ");
    Serial.println(send_data);
  
    clientt.send(send_data);
  }
}
bool debounce()
{
  return ((millis() - lastDebounceTime)> debounceDelay);
}
```

please help me to solve my problem and forgive me for any mistake in my english.

Comment: Can you try it with lower baudrate? If it doesn't work try with higher. Sometimes it make a sense.

Comment: I tried every available baudrate option. but still problem is same.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to use pull down (or pull up) resistors on the switches (the switch side of the pins)? Problem is if the 5V (i hope you don’t apply 5V to the pins?) falls away from the switch, the pins are floating.

Comment: I used ESP32 internal pull up registers . but problem is not with ESP and switches, they are working perfectly on breadboard or without fan connection.  The main problem is that whenever I try to control fan which is connected with relay or direct separated manual switch, it cause an error to ESP32 that continuously printing infinite weird chars. therefor every time I have to restart my ESP32 whenever this problem occur.       BTW thanks for reply.

Comment: Ah ok. Well the internals are pretty weak, but as you mention: probably the EMI is too strong. Produced by the motor of the blower; received by the traces of the esp ánd the wires (acting like an antenna). 

Distance could be helpful. And stronger pull up/down (like 2.2K/10K)

Comment: okay bro I will try stronger pull up register as you mentioned. I think at some  point you are right maybe ESP and wires act like antenna.  But as I mentioned above in my question that if I disconnect fan from main AC supply means totally cut off my ESP32 working perfectly. but whenever I connect ESP32 with direct AC or relay then this shitty fan cause error while operating manually or remotely.